# ¿Como mostrar div suscripción al hacer scroll con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de suscripción email, pero el formulario lo quiero añadir en una caja flotante.

> Como logro este mismo efecto, de este sitio web:
>   [http://es.wix.com/blog/](http://es.wix.com/blog/2016/10/crea-una-pagina-web-que-impulse-la-identidad-de-tu-marca/) utilizando solo **jQuery.**

Si pueden observar el efecto que posee la caja flotante del ejemplo del enlace, al hacer scroll muestra el contenido de suscripción:

- La posibilidad de poder cerrar la caja flotante **X**.
- Al suscribirte muestra una ventana de dialogo (Dando las gracias por la suscripción).
- Al refrescar la pagina la caja flotante de suscripción no aparece ya.

Cómo podría aplicar aquel efecto a este ejemplo de suscripción:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      $("#caja").addClass("entra");
    } else {
      $("#caja").removeClass("entra");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#contenedor {
  height: 900px;
}

#caja {
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  top: 200px;
  right: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(125,125,125,.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(125,125,125,.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(125,125,125,.2);
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  border: 1px solid rgba(125,125,125,.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#caja .x {
    position: absolute;
    right: 13px;
    top: 9px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #222;
}

#caja h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

#caja h1 i {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAXBAMAAACL/BAmAAAABGdBT…h0HuBDUqW+u6yjq+oFEfpAw+p5bL9nzB/zCv+7oz+3+QnbNC75apKiLQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    height: 23px;
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

#caja p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 14px 0 18px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#caja.entra {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="caja">
    <a href="#" class="x">X</a>
    <h1>¡Suscríbete al Blog!<i></i> </h1>
    <p>¿Quieres recibir los artículos directamente<br>
en tu email? Suscríbete aquí.</p>

   <form method="post" onsubmit="if ((/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/).test(this.email.value))subscribe(this.email.value);this.email.value='';return !1">
  <input type="email" required="required" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email"><input type="submit" value="Suscríbete">
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

> No desconozco el tema, anteriormente he creado menú de navegación utilizando este ejemplo [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/eqLrx0yg/) otros tipos de efectos [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/5d6pnp9d/) pero en este caso lo observo algo complicado.

Comment: Podría ayudarte https://github.com/peachananr/subscribe-better.

Comment: Hola @Dev.Joel el ejemplo que has indicado se ve muy bien, pero ya tengo mi sistema de suscripción con la funcionalidad de poder seleccionar la plantilla deseada desde el CMS. Podés ayudar en mí código cómo puedo mostrar una caja box al presionar el botón de suscripción tomando en cuenta si el email es correcto y si no existiera algún error, cómo le puedo añadir funcionalidad a la **x** para ocultar la caja. Otro tema era no mostrar la caja de suscripción si el usuario se suscribió crear una cokiee pero ésto lo podría solucionar directamente desde php, será posible que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: @Joel con algo similar al ejemplo de la página indicada amigo ;) Saludos!

Comment: Cerrar un elemento con jQuery es un simple hide: `$("#caja .x").click(function() {  $("#caja").hide();});` Que al refrescar no aparezca la caja si te has suscrito lo puse en mi respuesta con localStorage, si prefieres hacerlo con cookies sería algo parecido. Para abrir otra ventana al suscribirte es mostrar un div que tienes oculto dentro de la función `submit` que uso en mi ejemplo también (para mostar el código es igual que el `hide` pero poniendo `show`)

Comment: @blonfu Hola :) gracias por el ejemplo, podías editar tu respuesta para que la solución no quedé por partes, podías indicar al presionar el botón de suscripción a parezca una caja box y se oculte la caja de suscripción no digo del tema localStorage ni de la cookies sólo que al estar la caja box no estaría bién que se viera la caja de suscripción

Comment: Tienes mi respuesta con el jsfiddle, puedes hacer una copia y probar lo que te he comentado y si algo no funciona preguntas algo más concreto.

Answer (score 12):

Puedes usar la función `scroll()` para detectar cuando haces scroll y `scrollTop()` para saber en que posición del scroll estás y añadir una clase con una animación o animarlo con jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
      $("#caja").addClass("entra");
    } else {
      $("#caja").removeClass("entra");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#contenedor {
  height: 900px;
}

#caja {
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  right: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#caja.entra {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="caja">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque harum a, cum natus fugit quidem, odio ea. Error ad a placeat omnis tempora nisi rerum, minima earum, sed dolor?</div>
</div>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Para saber si se ha ingresado un email y no volver a mostrar el formulario se puede guardar un valor `localStorage` y quitar la clase que muestra el formulario de inscripción. Se podrá mejorar el código, lo mío es más el CSS pero puede servir como ejemplo (no me funciona en el snippet así que pongo un enlace a jsfiddle):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/e4y9p4Lu/4/

Comment: @May he editado mi respuesta y he puesto un ejemplo con `localStorage`. Quizá pueda valer como punto de partida

Comment: especifique que efecto tiene la caja flotante de aquella página, al final de la pregunta comenté que no desconozco el tema si he trabajado anteriormente con scroll. Entonces quedaría dos temas el de no mostrar la caja al suscribirte aún así refresque o recargue la página esto lo podría solucionar con PHP sin problemas. Solo quedaría un tema si el email es correcto al suscribirse mostrar una caja box una ventana de diálogo especificando algo en concreto gracias por suscribirte.

Comment: Pero eso puedes hacerlo igual que escondo la caja. Tendrías un bloque oculto que se muestra cuando le das al botón de enviar

Comment: en ese sentido claro que sería fácil mostrar cuando das al botón enviar pero si el correo no es válido no quiero mostrar el diálogo si no mostar un mensaje de error en la misma caja flotante donde se encuentra la suscripción, ahí también faltaría un pequeño detalle que es añadir un botón X a la caja flotante para ocultar la caja flotante.

Comment: borro mis comentarios anteriores porque ahora que los tuyos no están no tienen sentido. Deberías mostrar tu código y plantear la pregunta sobre eso.

Comment: Hola :) elimine los comentarios para evitar debate de comentarios, e añadido el diseño del formulario si puedes observar el código jquery en el ejemplo que me has añadido es similar a las demás preguntas y algunos ejemplos que he puesto al final de la pregunta. Por ello indique que el ejemplo dado me deja en la misma situación, lo deseado es al enviar mostrar una caja box y al refrescar no salga la caja flotante pero esto ya lo había mencionado que lo podía solucionar con php, otro detalle era poder añadir la x para esconder la caja flotante.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que te he entendido, y viendo el encabezado de la pregunta, yo hice lo mismo hace tiempo y lo único que tienes que hacer para el efecto flotante es usar en el estilo de tu formulario una posición fija. Sólo con eso ya se queda fijo hagas el scroll que hagas sin jquery ni ninguna otra librería. En mi caso usaba este código:

```css
#formSubscripcion {
 position: fixed;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
}
```

Eso te dejará fijo el elemento 'formSubscripcion' a un margen de 10 pixels de la esquina inferior derecha. Cámbialo a tu gusto con % o lo que necesites.

Si tu problema es evitar que salga después de suscribirte, lo puedes hacer quitando el objeto del árbol DOM.

```js
document.removeChild("formSubscripcion");
```

Puedes ver más funciones y practicar código y ejemplos en [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp).

Si necesitas más ayuda o algo de código dímelo y te respondo la parte que necesites pero con esto deberías de poder hacerlo rápido.

Comment: Hola @Awes0meM4n. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Quizás tu respuesta podría estar un poco más completa si agregaras un ejemplo de código con lo que estás explicando. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando algún caso concreto? Podrás encontrar más información en [answer].

Comment: Ya he añadido lo que me has sugerido. Espero que ahora quede más claro.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Hola amigo :) el ejemplo que me has indicado no es concreto el problema, edite mi pregunta publicado el diseño del formulario, ahora lo que quiero es Mostrar una caja box flotante al presionar el botón de suscripción mostrando un mensaje de gracias por la suscripción, pero solo si el email es válido o si no existió algún error, ahora en el diseño del formulario de suscripción en la × poder ocultar la caja de suscripción, el otro asunto era evitar que la caja aparezca si el usuario ya se suscribió ésto sería crear una cokiee.

Comment: Si ves el enlace a w3school verás que también existe el método "appendChild(element)". Cuando le den al botón de subscribir verificas que es un e-mail válido y si tienes respuesta OK de la subscripción. 
Luego usas document.getElementById("formSubscripcion").appendChild("formGracias") para añadir el mensaje agradeciendo la subscripción y al final removeChild para quitar lo que no necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el `div` o caja de suscripción aparezca cuando hagas un scroll con jQuery, necesitarás de la función `scrollTop()`: [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Ejemplo:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
        $("#suscribe").animate({
            right: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Con este ejemplo consigues que cuando la venta del navegador haya echo scroll hasta los 1000 píxeles o más, haga el `animate()` del `div` con id `subscribe`. Por supuesto, si usas animaciones con css, puedes agregar directamente una clase en vez de la función `animate()`.

También puedes añadir un else para volver a esconderlo.

La caja deberá estar con `position: fixed;` con sus `top/bottom, left/right` en las CSS, y recomendaría que esté fuera de cualquier otro elemento, como por ejemplo, justo despues de abrir la etiqueta `<body>` o antes de su cierre.

Comment: Hola @Cheshire ;) el tema que me has indicado no es exactamente lo que necesito creó que no fuí exactamente preciso a  mi problema al final de mi pregunta comenté que no desconozco del tema en este caso es lo que me has indicado. Lo que necesito en el código que he publicado en mi pregunta es realizar que al enviar el correo o mejor dicho al presionar el botón de suscripción tomando en cuenta que si los datos son válidos y si no hubo error alguno al enviar muestre una caja box con un mensaje que personalizare.

Comment: Ahora en la caja donde esta el formulario en la × darle funcionalidad es decir ocultar la caja al presionar la × otro tema era si el usuario se suscribió erar crear una cokiee para evitar que la caja de suscripción aparezca por x días, si puedes observar esa es la funcionalidad que cumple el ejemplo de la página? En conclusión esa era mi pregunta. Podés ayudar @Cheshire ;)